# Mapbox GL - Min/Max elevation in map bounds

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Does anyone know if there is a way to determine the min/max elevation of the area within the map bounds view when using mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Surface API](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/surface/) to find the elevation at a given location.

A possible approach would be to retrieve the elevation for a couple of points within the boundary and determine the min/max elevation approximately. The current limit of points per query is 300.

Take a look at the [Surface Playground](https://www.mapbox.com/labs/surface-playground/#)
To get the elevation: Select the `Mapbox Terrain` from the examples, then layer: `contour`, field: `ele`

Comment: Great idea, this should be a good enough solution for me if I send a sampling of 300 points.